# SharePoint-Users Contribute permissions still not able to edit

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a site at http://moss/sites/Electronics/Laptop

I have given users contribute permission on laptop site but still when they try to edit the page they are getting access denied, I have checked the permission level and all permissions are fine bt still users are not able to edit page.

I gave them read permissions on Electronics site and now they are able to edit the pages. My question is why we need to give them read permission on the top level site? What we don't want users to go to the top level site at all and want them to have an access on subsite only? Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: A few months back, I created new users for our intranet portal they had contribute access to one particular child site and they didn't have any access to top level sites. Not even readonly. Everything worked fine. We used active directory authentication. Wondering what went wrong in your case

Comment: If thats the case then could you guide me what permissions do i need to set at the child site, I added the active directory users into members group of child site but they are not able to edit? I saw one thing in contribute permissions:

Comment: Add and Customize Pages  -  Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a Windows SharePoint Services-compatible editor. .... this is unchecked...do we need to check this in order to edit pages?

Answer (score 0):

Does the user have any access to the child site before you granted access on the parent? If not, this is likely because you're using some reference to list data from the parent in the child. If the user has no access to the parent and the child is trying to access that data, it will fail and the user will get access denied regardless of their permissions on child.

If they had access but just couldn't edit, this could be a completely different problem but it isn't typical out-of-box behavior. I would still be suspicious that something from parent is being used in child to cause this contention.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered this in my 2010 installation. User has rights on a library, but Limited Access at the site level. Granting them Contribute at the site level resolved the issue, but this causes a long list of other issues relating to security.  That's an end-user\training issue I need to work on.

Just my $.02